# postForEntity does not produce correct JSON representation...At my wits end

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I am new to Spring MVC REST. I spent hours googling and trying different ways to solve this problem. 
Why does not this code produce JSON with double quotes???

```
            List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters = new ArrayList<HttpMessageConverter<?>>();            
        MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter mappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
        objectMapper.configure(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_UNQUOTED_FIELD_NAMES, true);
        mappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);
        mappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.setPrettyPrint(true);                    
        converters.add(mappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter);             
        template.setMessageConverters(converters);

        ResponseEntity<EAApplication> response = template.postForEntity(
            LOCAL_URI,
            requestEntity, EAApplication.class);
```

produces following JSON without double quotes and so server is sending 400 Bad Request.

```
{ applications:
[ { submissionDate: '2014-09-05T08:28:17',
   firstName: 'Mickey',
   lastName: 'Mouse',
   email: 'mm@disney.com',
   dietaryRestrictions: 'Cheese only',
   restSkillLevel: 'Novice',
   jsonSchemaSkillLevel: 'Expert',
   restStandardFamiliarity: true,
   slimFamiliarity: true,
   odataLibFamiliarity: true } ] }
```

Comment: Can we see your `requestEntity`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You client side code works perfectly fine. The 400 Bad request may be due to an error on your controller side which might not be able to handle the content.

The JSON that you pasted above does not have double quotes around it because some editors or programs render the JSON that way just to increase readability. The raw string after serializing through the postForEntity is actually generating JSON with double quotes.

The below mentioned code is working, I tested it by writing a test.

```
package com.test.rest.controller;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import ........    

public class TestAppController {

@Test
public void testController() throws Exception {

    Server mockServer = new Server(9190);
    startMockServer("query-rs-main.xml", "query-rs", mockServer);

    EAApplication requestEntity = new EAApplication();
    Application application = new Application();
    application.setDietaryRestrictions("Cheese only");
    application.setFirstName("Mickey");
    application.setLastName("Mouse");
    application.setEmail("mm@disney.com");
    application.setJsonSchemaSkillLevel("Expert");
    application.setRestSkillLevel("Novice");
    application.setSubmissionDate(new Date());
    application.setOdataLibFamiliarity(true);
    application.setRestStandardFamiliarity(true);

    List<Application> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(application);

    requestEntity.setApplications(list);

    RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate();

    List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters = new ArrayList<HttpMessageConverter<?>>();
    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter mappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
    objectMapper.configure(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_UNQUOTED_FIELD_NAMES, true);
    mappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);
    mappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.setPrettyPrint(true);
    converters.add(mappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter);
    template.setMessageConverters(converters);

    ResponseEntity<EAApplication> response = template.postForEntity(
            "http://localhost:9190/query-rs/eaapps",
            requestEntity, EAApplication.class);

    mockServer.stop();

}

public static void startMockServer(final String mainAppContextConfig, final String contextRoot, Server server) throws Exception {
    final DispatcherServlet servlet = new DispatcherServlet();
    servlet.setContextConfigLocation("classpath:" + mainAppContextConfig);
    final ServletHolder servletHolder = new ServletHolder(servlet);

    final ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler();
    context.setErrorHandler(null);
    context.setContextPath("/" + contextRoot);
    context.addServlet(servletHolder, "/*");

    server.setHandler(context);
    server.start();
}


}
```

Controller on the server side -

```
package com.yt.nss.rest.query.mock.controller;


import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import ....

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/eaapps")
public class EAApplicationsController {


@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<Object> submitMessage(final @RequestBody EAApplication eaApplication) {

    System.out.println(eaApplication);
    return new ResponseEntity<Object>(null, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

}

EAApplication class or POJO for transferring the JSON

```
@XmlRootElement
public class EAApplication {
private List<Application> applications;

public List<Application> getApplications() {
    return applications;
}

public void setApplications(List<Application> applications) {
    this.applications = applications;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "EAApplication{" +
            "applications=" + applications +
            '}';
}
}
```

When I ran the client and the server, the call was successfully made to the controller and EAApplication object on the controller method was fully populated.

I suggest you look at your controller and spring mvc configuration on the server side or post it here.

Comment: Are you saying that your mock server also received JSON without quotes around fieldnames i.e. exactly like mine? Was mock server able to correctly parse it? You said "The raw string after serializing through the postForEntity is actually generating JSON with double quotes." - I don't see that in your code. Unfortunately, I don't have access to Server side code.

Comment: Yes indeed. The Mock server was able to parse the JSON back into the object with all values sent by the client.

Comment: You can confirm it by looking at the output, the byte array looked like this with "pretty print" turned on in your configuration. [123, 13, 10, 32, 32, 34, 97, 112, 112, 108, ... ] here the 5th element is 34 (double quote) followed by 'applications'. You can put a breakpoint in com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize method and inspect the variable jgen._outputBuffer. You could also confirm it by using tcpdump to view the TCP packets going out to the server.

Comment: You are right, 400 Bad Request was not because of missing quotes as I had suspected. Server was correctly parsing it but complaining about incorrect enum value. Appreciate your prompt help and pointing me to right direction. Regards.